# Compile C++ code in gradle using CPP plugin

Tags: c++, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am working on gradle script where I am trying to complie the c++ code and my structure are as below.i am trying to compile my code on  below machine and it is showing the c++ compiler failed whereas I am not getting an issue with maven can somel

Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
└───src
    └───main
        ├───c++
        │   ├───headers   (headres is having **.h files)
        │   └───native    (native contains  **.cpp files)
        └───resources
            └───DSresources
                └───DSLib

apply plugin: 'cpp'
//-- set the group for publishing
group = 'com.rohit.singh'
/**
 * Initializing GAVC settings
 */
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream { 
    stream -> buildProperties.load(stream) 
} 
//add the jenkins build version to the version
def env = System.getenv()
if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) buildProperties.engineBuildVersion += "_${env["BUILD_NUMBER"]}"
version = buildProperties.engineBuildVersion
println "${version}"

//name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.rohit.singh"
version = buildProperties.engineBuildVersion
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"

model {
  components {
    main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
      targetPlatform "x86"
      targetPlatform "x64"
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            srcDir "src/main/c++/native"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the maven code snippet

```
profile>
            <id>Linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Linux</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>so</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-alpha-8</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>

                            <javahOS>linux</javahOS>

                            <compilerProvider>generic-classic</compilerProvider>
                            <compilerExecutable>g++</compilerExecutable>
                            <linkerExecutable>g++</linkerExecutable>
                            <sources>
                                <source>
                                    <directory>NativeJNI/../src/main/c++/native</directory>
                                    <fileNames>
                                        <fileName>JniSupport.cpp</fileName>
                                        <fileName>DiseaseStagingJni.cpp</fileName>
                                    </fileNames>
                                </source>
                            </sources>
                            <compilerStartOptions>
                                <compilerStartOption>-fPIC</compilerStartOption>
                            </compilerStartOptions>
                            <linkerFinalName>NativeJNI</linkerFinalName>
                            <linkerStartOptions>
                                <linkerStartOption>-shared -L${basedir}/src/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib -lds64 -Wl,-rpath,${basedir}/src/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib</linkerStartOption>
                            </linkerStartOptions>

                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>javah</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>LinuxNativeJNI</finalName>
                                    <javahOS>linux</javahOS>
                                    <javahProvider>default</javahProvider>
                                    <javahOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/custom-javah</javahOutputDirectory>
                                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
                                    <javahOutputFileName>DiseaseStagingJniWrapper.h</javahOutputFileName>
                                    <javahClassNames>
                                        <javahClassName>com.truvenwealth.analyticsengine.common.diseasestaging.DiseaseStagingJniWrapper</javahClassName>
                                    </javahClassNames>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>javah</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
```

Comment: As I said the error is saying the c++ compiler failed.I pasted my pom file snippet as in my question.

Comment: It appears that your `srcDir` does not include the `headers` directory. Can you check whether adding `srcDir "src/main/c++/headers"` resolves your issue?

Comment: Also, can you run gradle with the --info flag to get a more verbose output that may help in understanding the compilation failure?

Comment: I added it in my build.gradle script and getting the below error  but I don't understand why it is throing this error.My linux system is having the gcc complier                                                                                           .whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/libexec/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
       .Execution failed for task ':compileMainExecutableMainCpp'.
> No tool chain is available to build for platform 'linux_x86-64': Tool chain 'gcc' (GNU GCC):
    - Could not find C compiler 'gcc'. Searched in: /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: I saw if I commented the gcc path in my build.gradle script then it throws some different error it is trying to run the following task :compileMainExecutableMainCpp and trying to execute this  /applications/jenkins/workspace/NativeJNI/NativeJNI/src/main/c++/native/ds64.lib:2: error: stray ‘`’ in program and saying that C++ compiler failed

Answer (score 1):

I used the Javah function in below manner.

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply plugin: 'java'
//-- set the group for publishing
group = 'com.rohit.singh'

/**
 * Initializing GAVC settings
 */
def buildProperties = new Properties()
file("version.properties").withInputStream {
        stream -> buildProperties.load(stream)
}
//add the jenkins build version to the version
def env = System.getenv()
if (env["BUILD_NUMBER"]) buildProperties.ncdefBuildVersion += "_${env["BUILD_NUMBER"]}"
version = buildProperties.anal
println "${version}"

//name is set in the settings.gradle file
group = "com.rohit.singh"
version = buildProperties.anal
println "Building ${project.group}:${project.name}:${project.version}"

repositories {
    maven {
      url "http://xxx.tsh.xxon.com:x/factory/libslocal"
    }
     maven {
      url "http://xxx.tsh.xxon.com:x/factory/libs-release"
    }
}
    dependencies {
   compile ([
    "com.rohit.singh:engine-common:4.+"
      ])
}



model {
  repositories {
    libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
      jdk {
        headers.srcDirs "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/win32",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/darwin",
        "${System.properties['java.home']}/../include/linux"
      }
    }
  }
}

model {
  platforms {
    x64 { architecture "x86_64" }
    x86 { architecture "x86" }
  }
}

model {
  components {
    main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
      sources {
        cpp {
          source {
            lib library: 'main', linkage: 'static'
            lib library: 'jdk', linkage: 'api'
            srcDir "src/main/c++/native"
            include "**/JniSupport.cpp"
            include "**/DiseaseStagingJni.cpp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
//def compilePath = configurations.compile.resolve().collect {it.absolutePath}.join(";")
binaries.all {
    // Define toolchain-specific compiler and linker options
    if (toolChain in Gcc) {
        cppCompiler.args "-I${nativeHeadersDir}"
        cppCompiler.args "-g"
        linker.args '-Xlinker', '-shared -LNativeJNI/src/main/resources/DSresources/DSLib -lds64 -Wl'
}
}

**//def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
task nativeHeaders {
    // def nativeHeadersDir = file("$buildDir/nativeHeaders")
     def outputFile = file("$nativeHeadersDir/DiseaseStagingJniWrapper.h")
     def classes = [
             'com.abcedefgh.nice.common.diseasestaging.DiseaseStagingJniWrapper'
                  ]
     inputs.files sourceSets.main.output
     inputs.property('classes', classes)
     outputs.file outputFile
     doLast {
         outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
         def compilePath = configurations.compile.resolve().collect {it.absolutePath}.join(":")
         println "Using Compile Path: ${compilePath}"
         exec {
             executable org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getExecutable('javah')
             args '-o', outputFile
             args '-classpath', compilePath
             args classes
         }
     }
 }

             tasks.withType(CppCompile) { task ->
                 task.dependsOn nativeHeaders
             }**
//def filechange = file("NativeJNI-${project.version}.so")
//println filechange
task fixartifactname (type: Copy) {
       //def filechange = "NativeJNI-${project.version}.so"
       //println filechange
       from 'build/binaries/mainSharedLibrary'
       into 'build/libs'
def filechange = file("NativeJNI-${project.version}.so")
println filechange
include('libmain.so')
rename ('libmain.so', '${filechange}')
}
//println fixartifactname
build.dependsOn fixartifactname
```